# How to create new spring project with gradle in intellij having tomcat environment?

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I want to create gradle Spring MVC project in intellij with tomcat setup , and I also want to know, how to run it on local host. I am using Ubuntu OS.

Comment: http://start.spring.io

Answer (score 8):

In IDEA 14.1 you can use `File -> New -> Project... -> Spring Initializer` and select `Gradle Project` for `Type:`.
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/develop-spring-boot-applications-more-productively-with-intellij-idea-14-1/

Comment: this will create Spring Boot project, but he is asking about only Spring Project